# ELK EFK k8S postgresql

Tags: postgresql, rest, kubernetes, elk, efk

I have builded a K8s cluster with some pods mainly Restfull api that provides differents endpoints amongs storage data on postgresql pods .  I need to index tables from differents databases thus I can provide a global search on the frontend app . how could I implement this ?knowing  that Elasticsearch is a search engine based on the Lucene library that provides a distributed, multitenant-capable full-text search engine with an HTTP web interface and schema-free JSON documents. I m looking for best practices , optimisation architecture as well, so any help would be welcome!